# Generic Method Constraints?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a 2 classes that contain data that will populate separate grids. The grids are very similar, but different enough to require the use of 2 classes. Both grids contain a function called "GetDuplicates" and where I am implementing these classes, I have a method that checks if the class has duplicates and returns a message indicating so.

```
private bool HasDuplicates(FirstGridList firstList)
{
    var duplicates = firstList.FindDuplicates();
    if (duplicates.Count > 0)
    {
        // Do Something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I would like to be able to call that method using both FirstGridList and SecondGridList. I just don't know how to go about properly implementing the generic constraint then casting the generic input parameter to the correct type. Similar to:

```
private bool HasDuplicates<T>(T gridList)
{
    // Somehow cast the gridList to the specific type
    // either FirstGridList or SecondGridList

    // Both FirstGridList and SecondGridList have a method FindDuplicates
    // that both return a List<string>
    var duplicates = gridList.FindDuplicates();
    if (duplicates.Count > 0)
    {
        // Do Something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, the method does the same thing. Therefore I do not want to create this twice. I feel like this is possible, but I am thinking about it incorrectly. I am not exactly experienced with generics yet. Thank you.

Comment: Does `FirstGridList` and `SecondGridList` share the same base class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have both your grids implement a common interface like:

```
public interface IGridList
{
    public IList<string> FindDuplicates();
}
```

and then define your generic constraint based on this interface:

```
private bool HasDuplicates<T>(T gridList) where T: IGridList
{
    // Both FirstGridList and SecondGridList have a method FindDuplicates
    // that both return a List<string>
    var duplicates = gridList.FindDuplicates();
    if (duplicates.Count > 0)
    {
        // Do Something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Obviously both your `FirstGridList` and `SecondGridList` should implement the `IGridList` interface and the `FindDuplicates` method.

or you could even get rid of the generics at this stage:

```
private bool HasDuplicates(IGridList gridList)
{
    // Both FirstGridList and SecondGridList have a method FindDuplicates
    // that both return a List<string>
    var duplicates = gridList.FindDuplicates();
    if (duplicates.Count > 0)
    {
        // Do Something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

By the way at this stage you could even get rid of the `HasDuplicates` method as it doesn't bring much value to your application. I mean Object Oriented Programming existed long before things like generics or LINQ so why not use it:

```
IGridList gridList = ... get whatever implementation you like
bool hasDuplicates = gridList.FindDuplicates().Count > 0;
```

Seems reasonable and readable enough to any developer with basic C# culture. And of course it spares you a couple of lines of code. And remember that the more code you write the higher the probability to make mistakes.

Comment: At this point, you may even get rid of the generic `<T>` and just type it directly against `IGridList`.

Comment: Oh yeah Chris, you are perfectly right. I have updated my answer to include your remark. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair is it because T was used just inside the method and had an interface constraint? Can we generalize and say when you use a class or interface constraint, there is no need to use a Generic type if it used as an Input?

Comment: @MBen, absolutely, generics do not bring any value in this context.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov your suggested `gridList.FindDuplicates().Count` doesn't use any Linq methods.

Comment: Oops, sorry, yeah. I was thinking of an `IEnumerable<string>` and a `.Count()` extension method in the first place. Good spot. I will fix that.

Comment: Thank you! I saw a lot of information similar to what you showed just not as clearly laid out. I really do appreciate the clear and quick response.